# Concrete language as a manifestation of Being

Tags: philosophy-of-language, buddhism, heidegger

Foucault in the preface to *The Order of Things* wrote how he 'laughed out loud' when he discovered a Chinese Encyclopedia whose categorisation of knowledge was different from his European presuppositions.

When Heidegger, posits language as the house of Being; does he take into account the concrete manifestation of language? That is its script.

In Europe, the angular and straight lines of letters of the Roman Alphabet in its Capital form; carved in monuments and gravestones - the art form of the letter; does this represent *permanence* of the Greek/Roman/Christian tradition?

In Japan, one notes that the art of the letter - calligraphy - is different; it is painted in scrolls; and it is looser, and more fluid; does this represent *impermanence* of the Buddhist tradition?

Or am I positing a contrary that is not there?

Comment: @Tomono: I'm not concerned here with the etymology of language, though in part; but it's expressiveness. Which is why I'm considering the two calligraphic traditions.

Comment: And by its expressiveness; what it expresses.

Comment: Well it's a question really that can only be answered by art historian or it's correlative; it's a hard question to answer well - I would think etymology is part of this, but not the whole.

Comment: Many Indian Buddhist and Hindu monuments and scripts are carved in stone, despite sharing Japanese Buddhism's emphases on impermanence.

Comment: I think you're expressing a common misconception of Japanese "art of the letter". There are also blockish ways of writing characters. The link is going to be too distant to produce answers that are anything but opinion-based. (Also, Foucault uses a **Chinese** dictionary example -- not a Japanese one).

Comment: To my mind it's a good question in terms of building an essay around; but that I suppose isn't appropriate here.

Comment: @virmaior: I'm aware that there are different calligraphic styles in Japanese in a general kind of way; but I'd guess that there would be a number given what I have seen of Arabic calligraphy; for example the kufi script looks very linear, and hence 'modern'; but to be honest I wasn't expecting to get a good answer to this here; ok - I was quoting from memory; thxs for the correction. Still are the block type calligraphy are they associated with Buddhism? I mean you're not, I expect talking about printing;

Comment: Actually, Virmaior knows quite so well about Japanese culture. When I saw this question, it was sad to say it is not so clear to me what you would like to ask. If you had known wabi, sabi, which is **very hard to express in English** even reading Wiki says it has something to do with Buddhists' impermanence, but happening to being Japanese, I even disagree with. But as a moderator, as I happen to have known him at Japanese language site imposing your power so much is not good for your reputation, personally, I think?

Comment: @tomono: yes, I agree; I was just explaining why I asked the question - I wasn't criticising.

Comment: But I must admit when answering I am almost near to say "soooo what is your purpose to ask this?" but even though the question is a bit vague, I am doubtful if this should be put on hold. I am not saying this because I answered here only, but because I somehow started seeing put on hold on another topic about which I am concerned with the quality of the question if it is worth to be put on hold ( I mean, personally not worth putting on hold )

Comment: @tomono: well my purpose is two-fold; to encourage a wider range of questions and also because I am genuinely interested in calligraphy but don't know enough about it to ask a sufficiently detailed question that ties it with religous/philosophical traditions.

Comment: I am going to stop here, only what I wanted to say is, having seen a bit of put on holds, I would like ask for the reconsideration before imposing your influence, ( I am saying to moderators, please be reminded, Ullah, ) I just started feeling a bit concerned.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'm seeing a whole lot of moving parts in the question that make it seem difficult to answer with anything but an opinion. There are claims about West = permanence / East = impermanence. Then there's an observational claim about uses of the Roman alphabet in the West and "calligraphy" in the East. And finally what answers are supposed to do is agree or disagree with the claim that the observation shows the theory about East vs. West.

Comment: I can see either the first or second paragraphs as being good philosophical questions. The third paragraph seems to start a new question which seems like it would need to be answered by a lexicography historian. The fourth paragraph seems to be something that would first need to be supported with more data (living in Japan, while I do sometimes see scrolls that might fit that description, I also see hard-etched gravestones with solid straight lines dominating). E.g., all of these are ways of writing *kaze* (http://moji.tekkai.com/zoom/%E9%A2%A8/page.html); some traditional ones are  blockish

Comment: @virmaior: thanks for the link; sure, it's a very broad subject; it maybe that there is nothing in what was a casual observation in paragraph three, but it was a beginning, in a way, to answer or rather to discuss the question in paragraph two.

Comment: I wasn't by the way, claiming an essentialist difference between East/West; but using, perhaps incorrectly, Deleuzes notion of Juxtoposition.

Comment: Ullah, for productive purpose sake, please let me comment here for both of you. I think you guys, ( I mean you Ullah and Virmaior, both ) know really sooooooooo faaaarrr much more than I, here I am saying with no intention but just with pure honesty. And you know Virmaior is a well known person in Japanese language site and please understand he definitely understands the "subtlety" or how should I say "intricacy" or in a way "difficulties" about understanding Japanese culture.

Comment: ( Japan almost had had no real direct contact with outside until the Western culture "opened" ( for the trading purpose ) until 1853, see ). So that while I know you are too well educated too ( here I am saying with no evil intention ) but it seems here since I too had wondered how I could have answered as a native speaker  so, you know, I would like you to take it just one of the tragic questions you had happened to post unfortunately. ) Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize that I read mistakingly as I commented.

Regarding **your** question-theory.

I have to start from the explanation about the history of the old ( not so largely discovered ) Japan in order to tell about **Izumo Shrine**.

There are many theories about the history of Japan up until around 6th century.

It is widely held Japanese ( or Japan ) was called 倭(**[Wa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa_%28Japan%29)**) which means barbarians ( to Chinese at that time ). Now according to the **[Vol 30 of Records of the Three Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Records_of_the_Three_Kingdoms#Book_of_Wei_.28.E9.AD.8F.E6.9B.B8.29)**  ( See the lower page ), which was written by 陳寿 ( **[Chen Shou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_Shou)** ), around AD1-3, Japan seemed to have several countries centering around 邪馬台国 ( **[Yamataikoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamatai)** ) Now, it is widely held at the same era, **as I will mention later about Buddhism**, Japan had had **[Izumo Shrine](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e5804.html)** whose deity is and was **Okuninushi no Okami**, which has **nothing to do with Buddhism**. ( which indicates there might have been another different strong country against 邪馬台国 ( **[Yamataikoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamatai)** ( which later became the **main stream country** which leads to today's emperor )))

Now, Buddhism, according to 日本書記 ( **[Nihon-Shoki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihon_Shoki)** ), which was written theoritically after the **[Yamataikoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamatai)** conquered the main part of Japan ( Kyoto ), and was describing the old Japanese history and is written by **[traditional Chinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Chinese_characters)**, from which Japanese later created its own **[Kanji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji)** and **[Hiragana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana)** ( = leading to today's language ), was **imported** to Japan in the year of AD538 by some historians ( or around that year by many historians ).

Today's Hiragana, oldest being officially confirmed in 古今和歌集　( **[Kokin Wakashu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kokin_Wakash%C5%AB)** ), although the development of Buddhism was almost in the same line with the spreading of **Kanji** and **Hiragana**, but it ( = Buddhism ) was imported from China and still practiced with **Confucianism**, the latter of which fitted with the idea and morality of old Samurais, whose main focus as the above Wiki says was the **importance of the family**, suited with Lord-subordinate system in feudal era at that time, and has been practiced until at least 1868 around that time Japan has begun trading with The United Kingdom, The U.S, Russia so on.

Another counter proof is the existence of priests of **[the Society of Jesus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_Jesus)** in 16th centuries in Japan, who traveled from Europe in order to spread Christianity and also for the purpose of trading. Japanese Christian, at that time was called 切支丹　( **[Kirishitan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Christians_of_Japan)** ) who used Hiragana and Kanji to express their idea towards Christianity too, not Buddhism only.

So it is hard for me personally to relate the impermanence with the **style** of Japanese ( language ).

**So do I believe personally about European alphabet**.

And finally and most importantly you added Heidegger, even the Being is exsitable afte it is **badged**, then what exactly would you like to ask, sorry?

**Simply saying, even the speech or text which comes after speech is the most important to human existence, are you proposing the style of the language differenciates what Foucault laughted out loud?????????** I mean, the Western alphabets, which need the **collection of the alphabets to denote something**, differenciate the human Being itself because Asian Kanji is just a **thingnification ( but not entirely, linguistically speaking ) such as 人**, in English a person, **[expresssing the human being standing with two legs?](http://www.chinese-tools.com/learn/characters/character/20154.html)** and have you known before Buddha was born there had been a dynasties in China such as **[Chou empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty)** and **[their characters](http://www.art-virtue.com/history/origin/origin.htm)**?

Comment: So, according to the questioner, as I guess who supports Popper, but the questioner told this question may be up to the historian, what makes difference from your comment from the Marxian historic dialectics? I am not offending you, but I am more and more skeptical to Popperian way. We have to conduct test and test and test on the historical issue???? Anti-thesis is not usable? Just wondering.

Comment: Oh I am sorry I read mistakingly. -->Foucault in the preface to The Order of Things wrote how he **'laughed out loud'**, yes he is right.

Comment: I am sorry I wrote a lot, since you do not seem to know about Japanese history so much, but in short, to me there is no relationship between the impermanence and Japanese language considering its origin.

Comment: I was thinking more on the lines of [this](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_calligraphy) ie the calligraphic traditions.

Comment: I do not deny you, since Japanese Shodo ( Callgraphy ) has been connected with Zen among the warriors ( Samurais ) especially at the same time tea practice. http://zenfields.org/calligraphy/. However, I would not like to go into the explanation furthermore, let me end by saying you **might** be right when you link the Zen with Japanese calligraphy.

Comment: Though I said like above, kindly check http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/anderson/accessible_html/Zen%20and%20Tea%20Introduction%20HTML2/html_introduction2/web_data/file3.htm Connected with the conception of **Wabi  Sabi** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabi-sabi, Japanese especially Samurais **threw** many thoughts into many areas. ( Not limited to the calligraphy ).Thank you.